# Mysterious core data behavior retrieves empty objects on second fetch

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to display a list of objects from Core Data into a UITableViewController. Here is the viewWillAppear of this UITableViewController:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.landmarks = [[TSDataManager sharedInstance] fetchArrayFromDBWithEntity:@"Landmark" forKey:nil withPredicate:nil];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

And here is the fetchArrayFromDBWithEntity:forKey:withPredicate: implementation:

```
- (NSMutableArray*)fetchArrayFromDBWithEntity:(NSString*)entityName forKey:(NSString*)keyName withPredicate:(NSPredicate*)predicate {
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    if(keyName != nil){
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:keyName ascending:NO];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
        [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    }

    if (predicate != nil){
        [request setPredicate:predicate];
    }

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }
    return mutableFetchResults;
}
```

When the table first appears, everything is displayed correctly, I have 4 objects coming back from the DB with titles that are correctly displayed in each cell.

But whenever I go to another view and come back, the table has four objects alright, but the value of their "title" property is nil!

Here is the code of my Landmark class:

```
@interface Landmark : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * title;
@end

@implementation Landmark
@dynamic title;
@end
```

And here is how my table cells are constructed, in case it comes from there:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"LandmarkCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Landmark *landmark = (Landmark *) self.landmarks[(NSUInteger) indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = landmark.title;

    return cell;
}
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong here, but I seriously can't figure out what.

Comment: Are you absolutely positive that the property is using dynamic for it's properties? I had the same problem awhile back due to using synthesize instead of dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the problem came from my implementation of Core Data as a singleton.  I replaced it with NLCoreData (https://github.com/jksk/NLCoreData) and everything is working fine now.

Comment: You should definitely look into NSFetchedResultsController. It seems that you are using Core Data not how it is intended to be used. Every "manual" fetch you execute is a sign of using Core Data the wrong way.